# Jquery from PHP replace DIV content

Tags: jquery, html, replace

In page I have excerption post with "read more" at end of excerption, so I try to replace content of div which contain excerption with full length of post with click on "read more". When click on "read more" nothing happen on click event.
Here is peace of code in my function.php

```
 if ($show_more_tag) {
        $excerpt = $excerpt.' <a class="more-link" href="'.$perma_link.'">'.$more_tag.'</a>';
        /* JQuery Start*/
                   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                     $(".more-link").click(function(event) {
                    $(this).parent("div").load($(this).attr("href")); //load the data
                    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from following the link
                      });
                    </script>';
        /* JQuery End */
    }
```

Where is mistake? Please help this is my first try to make something for web.

THANKS ALL OF YOU! This is code which work for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('.more-link').click(function(event) 
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parents('div:eq(0)').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #container', function()
            {
                $('#container .PicturePlaceHolder a').each(function(index, el) 
                    {
                    $(el).addClass('fancybox');
                    });
                    $('#container .fancybox').fancybox(
                    {
                    'transitionIn' : 'elastic', 
                    'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
                    'centerOnScroll': 'true',
                    'cyclic' : 'true'
                    });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the jquery code to single place in the page, within a `$(document).ready` call?

Comment: Have you tried putting an alert inside the click event just to check if it even gets there?

Comment: Why are you printing out the javascript with javascript? No need for that, just add it to the page as jaudette suggested.

Comment: nop, this is in functions.php of wordpress, so if I must place this in some other place where it should be?

Comment: You surely have a footer.php file in your theme. Just put it in there, above `</body>`.

Comment: I will try and anounce what happen, thx

Comment: Code is placed in footer above </body> without echo and stil nothing happen when click on link "read more"

Comment: @ jaudette: did you mean this:
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($(document).ready) {
                         $('.more-link').click(function(event) {
                        $(this).parent('div').load($(this).attr('href')); //load the data
                        event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from following the link
                          });
    };
</script>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting the script before the actual content. Because of this the $('.more-link') selector does not match anything. Wrap your JS code in a document.ready callback:

```
 /* JQuery Start*/
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
   $(".more-link").click(function(event) {
     $(this).parent("div").load($(this).attr("href")); //load the data
     event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from following the link
   });
});
</script>';
/* JQuery End */
```

Comment: Code is now in footer.php just above </body> and look like this:
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
                         $('.more-link').click(function(event) {
                        $(this).parent('div').load($(this).attr('href')); //load the data
                        event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from following the link
                          });
    });
</script>
</body>


But nothing jet.

Comment: Do you have jQuery? Is it working in noConflict mode? Check the console for any JS errors

Comment: finally I found where is mistake: <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $('.more-link').click(function(event) { $(this).parents('div:eq(0)').load($(this).attr('href')); //load the data event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from following the link }); }); </script> here is for someone hwo maybe have same problem.

Comment: @SemirResimović Maybe you just need $(this).closest('div');